# syslog written on console

Tags: linux, unix, solaris, syslog

I have odd problem with syslog local7, my syslog configure the syslog to be written to

`local7.info    /var/log/syslog_info`

it's working just fine for years but recent days one device syslog message written on console and I don't know why this one device syslog on console but other hundreds of devices syslog still written on the file. my question question is how I can stop that? i need syslog from that device so i don't want to stop it but the same time i don't want to written on my console. my Os is 64 bit Solaris.
thanks,

this is my syslog.conf

```
  #
  *.err;kern.notice;auth.notice         /dev/sysmsg
  *.err;kern.debug;daemon.notice;mail.crit  /var/adm/messages

  *.alert;kern.err;daemon.err           operator
  *.alert                       root

  *.emerg                       *

  # if a non-loghost machine chooses to have authentication messages
  # sent to the loghost machine, un-comment out the following line:
  #auth.notice          ifdef(`LOGHOST', /var/log/authlog, @loghost)

  mail.debug            ifdef(`LOGHOST', /var/log/syslog, @loghost)

 #
 # non-loghost machines will use the following lines to cause "user"
 # log messages to be logged locally.
  #
 ifdef(`LOGHOST', ,
 user.err                   /dev/sysmsg
 user.err                   /var/adm/messages
 user.alert                 `root, operator'
 user.emerg                 *
 )
 local7.info        /var/log/syslog_info
```

Comment: Can you post your syslog configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `syslog` configuration will log anything at `err` level and above to the system console due to this line:

```
 *.err;kern.notice;auth.notice         /dev/sysmsg
```

This logs everything at `err` and higher, `kern` messages at `notice` and higher, and `auth` message at `notice` and higher to the system console.  If your device is logging messages at these levels this would explain the console messages.

You can suppress messages from the `local7` facility using the `none` qualifier, like this:

```
*.err;kern.notice;auth.notice;local7.none         /dev/sysmsg
```

Try that and see if the console messages stop appearing.

Comment: great, that's solve the issue. thanks much for you time and good explanation.

Comment: @eli1128, If this answered your question, please consider taking a moment to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.  Thanks!